# Is an empty aliasing shared_ptr a good alternative to a no-op deleting shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Sometimes I need `shared_ptr` instances that have a no-op deleter, because an API expects a `shared_ptr` instance that it wants to store for a limited time but I am given a raw pointer that I am not allowed to own for a time larger than what I am running for.

For this case, I have been using a no-op deleter, such as `[](const void *){}`, but today I found that there's another alternative to that, using (or abusing?) the [aliasing constructor](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/shared-ptr-secret-constructor.html) of `shared_ptr`:

```
void f(ExpectedClass *ec) {
   std::shared_ptr<ExpectedClass> p(std::shared_ptr<void>(), ec);
   assert(p.use_count() == 0 && p.get() != nullptr);
   apiCall(p);
}
```

My question is, what is the better way to do this and why? Are the performance expectations the same? With a no-op deleter I expect to pay some cost for the storage of the deleter and reference count, which doesn't appear to be the case when using the aliasing constructor with the empty `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Yeah, there's a note mentioning this oddity in  [util.smartptr.shared.const]/16. IMHO it's kinda the corollary of the fact that you can have a non-empty `shared_ptr` storing null (`shared_ptr<T>((T*)nullptr)`). Potentially a bit confusing, but valid. One problem with this usage is that copies of `p` do not share ownership with it, because neither of them owns anything. That could matter for some uses that expect to check for objects sharing ownership (via `owner_less`) but probably isn't an issue for the usage you describe.

Comment: @JonathanWakely thanks for the note. The note prior to it /15) confuses me. Why does the user have to make sure that `p` remains valid until the ownership group of `r` is destroyed in `shared_ptr<>(r, p)`? I thought that's the business of `shared_ptr`. If I just store it away, the aliasing pointer will always be valid because it prevents the ownership group of `r` from being destroyed, so that the user can "copy and forget" about it, or am I missing something?

Comment: Ah I see what it means. In case that the lifetime of `p` is not bound to the lifetime of `r` (which is allowed), then the lifeness of `r` does not imply the lifeness of `p` and then the user has to guarantee that.

Comment: @JonathanWakely BTW is `shared_ptr()` and `shared_ptr(shared_ptr(), nullptr)` equivalent (except for the `constexpr`)?

Comment: The aliasing constructor is `noexcept` and so is the default ctor of `shared_ptr`. There's no memory allocation.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, yes, I believe the results are equivalent. For the first question, your follow-up comment is exactly right. Consider `struct A { int i; }; void foo() { auto p1 = make_shared<A>(); shared_ptr<int> p2(p1, p1->i); int i; shared_ptr<int> p3(p1, i); return p3; }`, here `p2` meets that requirement, `p1->i` is valid as long as the ownership group of `p1` is valid, but `p3` fails that requirement, the local variable `i` goes out of scope before the use count of the ownership group reaches zero, making `*foo()` undefined behaviour. That's what the note in /15 means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick bench with

```
#include <memory>

static void aliasConstructor(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    int j = 0;
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr(std::shared_ptr<void>(), &j);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ptr);
  }
}

BENCHMARK(aliasConstructor);

static void NoOpDestructor(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    int j = 0;
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr(&j, [](int*){});
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ptr);
  }
}

BENCHMARK(NoOpDestructor);
```

gives

- [a ratio of 1/30 for gcc 10.2](https://quick-bench.com/q/bB-LStmUDD5eORLK8gfjhUNVvAU)
- [a ratio of 1/25 for clang 11 libc++](https://quick-bench.com/q/hPlEFCk6rnRJemIAsQOfQcB4OoI)

So alias constructor wins.

Answer (score 7):

Concerning performance, the following benchmark shows erratic figures:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <memory>

template <typename... Args>
auto test(Args&&... args) {
    using clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    auto best = clock::duration::max();

    for (int outer = 1; outer < 10000; ++outer) {
        auto now = clock::now();

        for (int inner = 1; inner < 20000; ++inner)
            std::shared_ptr<int> sh(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        auto time = clock::now()-now;
        if (time < best) {
            best = time;
            outer = 1;
        }
    }

    return best.count();
}

int main()
{
    int j;

    std::cout << "With aliasing ctor: " << test(std::shared_ptr<void>(), &j) << '\n'
              << "With empty deleter: " << test(&j, [] (auto) {});
}
```

Output on my machine with `clang++ -march=native -O2`:

```
With aliasing ctor: 11812
With empty deleter: 651502
```

GCC with identical options gives an even larger ratio, 5921:465794.
And Clang with `-stdlib=libc++` yields a whopping 12:613175.

Comment: In fact with libc++, the shared_ptr parts are completely optimized away when using the aliasing hack: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84b6d94a03d180b5

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb …What's that language it emits?

Comment: it's the intermediate language (LLVM IR) before converted to x86 assembly. I find it easier to crasp, especially the loops, since it's still in SSA form.

Comment: The difference is because the first does not allocate new memory (it only stores a pointer to already existing control block), while the second one allocates a new control block every time on shared pointer creation.

Comment: @IlyaPopov will the first even allocate any memory at all?

Comment: As far as I understand, it should, but only once - when the empty shared pointer is created in the `main()`.

Comment: @IlyaPopov No, default constructing a shared_ptr doesn't allocate anything.

Comment: @T.C. Correct, thank you. This means that the first will not allocate any memory, and not perform any refcounting at all.