# Passing a row `(*sp)[i]` of a matrix `shared_ptr<vector<vector<T>> sp` to a function which accepts a `shared_ptr<vector<T>>`

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I have a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::vector<double>> sp` and need to pass `(*sp)[i]`, for some `i`, to a function `foo` which accepts a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>>`. How can I do that?

One option would be `foo(std::make_shared<std::vector<double>>((*sp)[i])`, but that would create a copy of the vector `(*sp)[i]`. Since `(*sp)[i]` might be huge, I absolutely don't want that to happen.

So, is there any option to pass `(*sp)[i]` to `foo` without making a copy?

**EDIT**: Maybe we could do the following:

```
foo(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>>(&(*sp)[i], [](std::vector<double>* p) { }));
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible. Why does that function take in a `shared_ptr` in the first place ?

Comment: There is an aliasing constructor for `std::shared_ptr`. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/19102034/ or http://codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/04/25/shared-ptr-aliasing-constructor/

Comment: @Quentin Maybe we could provide a custom *delete function* which is a no-op. Please take note of my edit.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I was brilliantly disproved. Thanks for the question, I learnt something cool :)

Comment: If you create a new `shared_ptr` with a custom no-op deleter, you'll have to allocate a new control block. Better use the aliasing constructor, which reuses the existing control block.

Comment: Anyway, if you think you need to use a no-op deleter, you should [still use the aliasing constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31636869/is-an-empty-aliasing-shared-ptr-a-good-alternative-to-a-no-op-deleting-shared-pt).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the aliasing constructor.

```
foo(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>>(sp, &(*sp)[i]));
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do. Thanks! However, the option I came up with in my edit should "at least work" too, right?

Comment: That won't keep the parent matrix alive while the child row is in use. And, if you don't want the function to affect it's argument's lifetime, you shouldn't be passing a `shared_ptr` in the first place

Comment: @0xbadf00d That depends on what `foo` wants to do with the `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Useless Just to clarify (for the benefit of others), you are talking about the empty-deleter approach, correct?

Comment: Exactly: the empty deleter approach from OP's edit doesn't manage the parent lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your best options would be to either

A) Change foo to accept a reference to the shared_ptr, which would eliminate passing by value.

Or

B) Use std::move to move your shared_ptr into foo, and then ensure you don't reference sp after the call.

Like Quentin said, it's otherwise not possible with your current setup.

Comment: What do you think about the option I came up with in my edit?